# How to complete an converging parallal gateway in test

Tags: junit, camunda

I wrote some JUnit-tests on my process. In some cases I used

```
RuntimeService
.createProcessInstanceByKey("ID") //
.startBeforeActivity("taskID") //
.setVariables(map) //
.execute()
```

to start a process from a given task (not from the beginning).

This works well so far. In one case, the starting task is in one of two flows after a parallel gateway. The process now just executes until it reaches the 'end' gateway of this parallel flow.

Is there a way to 'mock' that missing token on the second incoming sequence flow?
I hope, you understood me ;-)

Comment: I now belief the better solution is to test this starting normally at the beginning of process.  The possible solution would be interesting anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute

```
runtimeService
  .createProcessInstanceModification(processInstanceId)
  .startBeforeActivity(idOfGateway)
  .execute();
```

If there are `n` missing tokens make sure to call `#startBeforeActivity` `n` times.

Comment: OK. That's really an easy idea ;) It means, that I have to mock some more tasks, but I'll give it a go. Thx